# Left outer joins aggregate first

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE categories(
  id SERIAL,
);

CREATE TABLE category_translations(
  id SERIAL,
  name varchar not null,
  locale varchar not null, 
  category_id integer not null
);

CREATE TABLE products(
  id SERIAL,
  category_id integer not null
);

CREATE TABLE line_items(
  id SERIAL,
  total_cents integer
  product_id integer not null
);
```

What I'm trying to do is output a map of each category name to the sum of total of its associated `line_items` `total_cents`. Something like:

| name | sum_total_cents |
| --- | --- |
| Fresh foods | 100000 |
| Dry products | 532000 |

There is  a uniqueness constraint that only one name for each locale will be stored. So a `category` will have one row for each locale stored in the `category_translations` table

What I currently have is

```sql
SELECT SUM(line_items.total_cents) AS sum_total_cents, ???
FROM line_items INNER JOIN products ON products.id = line_items.product_id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_translations ON category_translations.category_id = categories.id 
WHERE category_translations.locale ='en'
GROUP BY categories.id
```

I'm looking for an aggregate function to return the first `name` for the category. The only piece missing is that what to be written instead of the `???` as I've been facing a lot of `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` errors. In pseudo-code I'm looking for a `FIRST()` aggregate method in `PostgreSQL` that I can use

Comment: Avoid the use of old `SERIAL` and use `IDENTITY` instead.

Comment: "...the first name for the category..." -- there's no such thing. Do you mean any name at random? Remember the rows do not have inherent ordering in relational databases.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have a uniqueness constraint that only one name for each locale will be stored in the table. So a `category` will have one row for each locale stored in the `category_translations` table

Comment: That's perfectly OK, but still you have multiple names per category. Which one do you want to pick? All those multiple names don't have ordering, so there's no "first one".

Comment: @TheImpaler In the original post, I had a `WHERE` clause added `WHERE category_translations.locale ='en'` on the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so this will return only the english name

Comment: If you have `WHERE category_translations.locale ='en'`, you've effectively changed the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  You can just add `MAX(category_translations.name) AS name` to the select list to avoid the error.  The error is just referring to a _functional dependence_ requirement.  No need for a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want one *random* name from any locale, you can do:

```
select
  c.id,
  (select name from category_translations t 
   where t.category_id = c.id limit 1) as name,
  sum(i.total_cents) as sum_total_cents
from categories c
left join products p on p.category_id = c.id
left join line_items i on i.product_id = p.id
group by c.id, name
```

Alternatively, if you want the category name for the locale 'en' then you can do:

```
select
  c.id,
  (select t.name from category_translations t 
   where t.category_id = c.id and t.locale ='en') as name,
  sum(i.total_cents) as sum_total_cents
from categories c
left join products p on p.category_id = c.id
left join line_items i on i.product_id = p.id
group by c.id, name
```

Comment: Your answer worked. As an alternative:
`sql
SELECT SUM(line_items.total_cents) AS sum_total_cents, (array_agg(name ORDER BY category_translations.id ASC))[1] as name
FROM line_items INNER JOIN products ON products.id = line_items.product_id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_translations ON category_translations.category_id = categories.id 
WHERE category_translations.locale ='en'
GROUP BY categories.id
`
Also simply worked

Thanks!

Comment: @bmaw Just a note. You are using `INNER JOIN` there, That will work well when a category has at least 1 product and each product has at least 1 line. If that's not the case, you may want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.